# Using Puppetlabs-mysql to allow more than one host

Tags: mysql, database, puppet, puppetlabs-mysql

I am using **Puppet** v3.4.3 and **Puppetlabs-mysql** module v2.3.1 ( https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql) to create database and I need to allow hosts **localhost** and **%** to use it. Both Puppet master and client run on Ubuntu-14.04 servers.

I use code like this:

```
mysql::db { 'mydb':
  user     => 'myuser',
  password => 'mypass',
  host     => 'localhost',
  grant    => ['SELECT', 'UPDATE'],
}
```

If I try to pass both hosts as an array they get combined together:

```
host => ['localhost', '%'],
Mysql users:
| user             | host              |
+------------------+-------------------+
| username         | localhost%        |
```

If I try giving host-parameter twice I get error about duplicate declaration:

```
Error 400 on SERVER: Duplicate parameter 'host' for on Mysql::Db
```

Is what I want possible with this Puppet-module and if so how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create one grant with your `mysql::db`, as in your first example. To allow the other host, you need to add a dedicated [mysql::grant](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql#mysql_grant).